# Can two classes have the same set of names for their public classes and variables C++?

Tags: c++, class

I am not using inheritance or polymorphism. Would creating an instance of each class, and accessing their public classes and variables cause problems?

Comment: I'm assuming a valid rephrasing of the question is *"Can different unrelated classes use the same member names?"*  Yes, they can.

Comment: Probably. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You should probably add an example, because your explanation isn't very clear at all.

Comment: Each class uses a new name space and names used in a class do not conflict with other classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer(s)

You seem to have asked a question and then its inverse. Here are the answers:

> Can two classes have the same set of names for their public classes and variables C++?

Yes.

> Would creating an instance of each class, and accessing their public classes and variables cause problems?

No.

---

#### Long answer

Names declared inside of a namespace or a type (such as a class type) are *encapsulated*. They do not conflict with names declared inside *other* namespaces or types. The only exception is in their *use*, which can be ambiguous in some situations.